# GUI.matrix and GUIToScreenRect/ScreenToGUIRect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have strange behavior when use GUI.matrix and try convert space between GUI and Screen

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.Scale(Vector3.one * 2f);

    var screenRect = GUIUtility.GUIToScreenRect(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100));
    var guiRect = GUIUtility.ScreenToGUIRect(screenRect);

    Debug.Log(guiRect);
    // >> (x:99.50, y:90.50, width:100.00, height:100.00)
}
```

Is there any way to fix it?